# Connection string to SQL Server 2012 SP1 from SQL Server 2005 SP3

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, connection-string

I have a table on a SQL Server 2005 SP3 system and has server name and a connection string in a table called `SQLServer`.

An SSIS package looks at this table and uses the connection string data to fire off a bunch of other packages that gather data in regards to all SQL Servers on my network.  (Disk Usage, DB size, Backup / Job details, etc. etc.)  A very solid amount of data for administration and auditing purposes.

I have a handful of systems being used with ease, until now.  I have a new SQL Server 2012 Standard SP1 system in production, but cannot for the life of me get the SQL Server 2005 SP3 system to talk to the SQL Server 2012 system successfully.

Here are samples connection strings I have working:

(All are SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2)

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Data Source=CLE-SQL01;Persist Security Info=True;Password=****;User ID=****;Initial Catalog=master 

Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Data Source=SFO-SQL01;Persist Security Info=True;Password=****;User ID=****;Initial Catalog=master
```

Here is what I'm attempting to use as a connection string for the SQL Server 2012 Standard SP1:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=EXP1-SQL01;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=master;User=****;Pwd=****;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

This is the error I get when attempting to run the SSIS package that grabs all detail from this table for the SQL Servers data.

> TEW\srv.sql. ...ersion 9.00.4035.00 for 32-bit  Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  9:31:51 AM
>   Error: 2014-10-30 09:32:06.91     Code: 0xC0202009     Source:
>   SQLInventory Connection manager "Dynamic SQL Connection"
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80040154.  An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154 
>   Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2014-10-30
>   09:32:06.91     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: SQLInventory Connection
>   manager "Dynamic SQL Connection"     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80040154.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB
>   Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not
>   registered".  End Error  Error: 2014-10-30 09:32:06.91     Code:
>   0xC020801C     Source: Data ...  The package execution fa...  The step
>   failed.,00:00:16,0,0,,,,0

Any thoughts or ideas as to why this will not connect for me?  Any and all assistance / guidance would be far beyond appreciated.

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling SSIS to use the user/password as supplied in the connection string AND use the user that is running the SSIS package.  Which is more than likely the problem.  Change the string to

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=EXP1-SQL01;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=master;User=****;Pwd=****;
```

Here is a link to a great site that explains connection strings

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Negative.  Still get the same exact error message on my original post.  (Just different time stamps, obviously)